# LR Develop Module showing negative image!

Tags: lightroom

When switching to develop mode in Adobe Lightroom, the image changes to what appears to be a color negative with no presets. How can that be corrected?

Comment: Does this happen to all images?  Only some?  Are they camera images, scans, jpgs, RAWs?  What happens if you use the 'reset' button on the image (bottom right of Lightroom development module).  After you've gone to the develop module, what happens to the image in the library module if you go back without making changes, does the preview update to this 'negative' view?

Comment: What is "LR365"? "LR" typically refers to Adobe Lightroom, and my guess is you intend "365" to refer to a version number, but there was no v3.6.5 as far as I know; v3.6 is the closest.

Answer (score 1):

You may have accidentally enabled the [visualize spots](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/enhanced-spot-removal.html) feature, either by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> in Develop mode or checking the box below the photo while the spot removal tool was selected. (<kbd>Q</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit > Preferences > Performance, and uncheck Use graphics processor.

Comment: You should elaborate on why this would be helpful. As it stands, this answer is not very helpful even if it is correct.

Comment: To reviewers: This answer is so useful that I signed up to Photography.SE to up-vote it. Unless this is a duplicate question, please don't delete this answer - instead, it would be nice if any knowledgeable members of the community can help by fleshing out the answer.